# Compile errors with boost::geometry::distance

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am trying to compile a program that uses boost::geometry::distance to calculate the distance between two rectangles in an engineering project.  I get linker errors:

> /usr/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/not_implemented.hpp:64:5:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************
>   (boost::geometry::nyi::not_implemented_error::THIS_OPERATION_IS_NOT_OR_NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED::************)(mpl_::assert_::types))’
>        BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
>
> /usr/include/boost/geometry/algorithms/distance.hpp:546:55: error:
>   ‘apply’ is not a member of
>   ‘boost::geometry::dispatch::distance
>
> > , boost::geometry::model::polygon
> >     , boost::geometry::strategy::distance::pythagoras<>, boost::geometry::polygon_tag, boost::geometry::polygon_tag,
> >     boost::geometry::strategy_tag_distance_point_point, false>’
> >     ::apply(geometry1, geometry2, strategy);

It's not obvious what the problem is to my naive eyes.  If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful.  Important info:

boost 1.55 from yum on f21
gcc 4.9.2

As you can see below, I have made sure that the boost polygons are closed properly, and I also tried to correct them, but this did not solve the problem unfortunately.  Offending source code (rectangles are "block" objects):

```
double Block::measureDistanceBoost(const Block& otherblock)
{
    //Using boost geometry

    int i;

    double result=0.0;

    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> boostpoint;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<boostpoint> boostpoly;

    using boost::geometry::append;
    using boost::geometry::make;
    using boost::geometry::correct;

    boostpoly mypoly;
    boostpoly testpoly;
    std::deque<boostpoly> output; // discarded for now, maybe useful for visualisation later


    //Make a boost polygon out of my block points
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        append( mypoly, make<boostpoint>(this->worldPts[i].getx(), this->worldPts[i].gety()) );
    }

    //Boost polygons have to form a complete loop, add the first point again
    append( mypoly, make<boostpoint>(this->worldPts[0].getx(), this->worldPts[0].gety()) );


    //Make a boost polygon out of the test block points
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        append( testpoly, make<boostpoint>(otherblock.worldPts[i].getx(), otherblock.worldPts[i].gety()) );
    }

    //Like above, form a complete loop with first point
    append( testpoly, make<boostpoint>(otherblock.worldPts[0].getx(), otherblock.worldPts[0].gety()) );

    correct(testpoly);
    correct(mypoly);

    //Use boost::geometry::distance to measure the distance between the blocks
    //result = 0.0;
    result = boost::geometry::distance(mypoly, testpoly);


    return(result);
}
```

Comment: If you look at the table [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/distance/distance_2.html#geometry.reference.algorithms.distance.distance_2.supported_geometries) you'll see that, as the assertion states, the distance between polygon and polygon is not implemented in Boost 1.55. If you look at the docs for [1.56 or later](http://www.boost.org/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/distance/distance_2.html#geometry.reference.algorithms.distance.distance_2.supported_geometries) you can see that it is, so you can try updating.